# Mirroring threaded object to create a 3D printed coupler

Tags: mirror, 3d-printing, mirror-modifier

When I create a threaded female object (with garden hose threads) it works great.

[image: See image 1]

but when I **mirror the object and print it** out with the **mirrored threads** seems to get messed up / reversed somehow how can I fix this?

[image: See image 2]

I've attached / included the blend file.
[image]

Comment: could you please say more precisely what is messed up? If you plan to print you need to make sure that your object is manifold

Comment: Sure, when I print the coupler the bottom side threads / section screws correctly but the mirrored threads top section doesn't screw correctly.   I did apply the modifier and made it manifold. I'm printing it now to see if that helps.

Comment: the Mirror will inverse the topology, so maybe what you want is simply duplicate the mesh?

Comment: That may explain why the threads won't screw correctly (hard to tell the threads get changed using the mirror modifier just by looking at it) I guess I can't use the mirror modifier with threads.

Comment: One end of the coupler is _not_ a reflection of the other end. It's a _rotation_ through 180. (visualise physically moving a single male from one end to the other) I've just had a go at your file, though, and the ends don't match. You could build this without booleans.. ( a female thread is just a male thread turned inside-out, with a bit of slack )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This set of modifiers worked with an **empty** with a rotation on **X** at **180**.

[image: img0]

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 1):

When you mirror the object, the threads direction(clockwise or counter-clockwise) will be mirrored as well.

Since both screws are presumably both clockwise or counterclockwise, one or the other will not work.

The way to fix this is to use the [array modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html), with "relative offset" set to (0,0,1)(double on the z axis without mirroring). If you want them to clip, you can set it to lower than 1.

[image: the modifier]

[image: the result]

This also allows you to change the height of the threaded object, in either direction, without having to change the position.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't make the coupler correctly it just stacks them up on top of each other.  That's why I wanted to use the mirror modifier but cant since it alters the threads.